# Some of the win32 api calls are not working during a remote desktop session

Tags: c++, winapi, atl, remote-desktop

I have a modeless dialog which I would like to hide for a split second then take a screenshot, then show again. I have tried a few methods like moving the dialog off the screen using the `MoveWindow()` api call as well as the `SetWindowPos()` and even `ShowWindow(SW_HIDE)` none of these seem to be giving me the results I want because my dialog is still contained in the screenshot. If I launch solution during a non remote desktop session, my dialog hides, and it takes the screenshot perfectly. Is there something I am missing when it comes to remote desktop sessions and the win32 api calls? I have also tried using `InvalidateRect()` followed by `UpdateWindow()` and have tried `RedrawWindow()` to no avail. I am using ATL.

Comment: That did not used to work in the olden days either.  You had to wait until the windows below the hidden window repainted themselves, replacing the pixels.  That is no longer necessary thanks to the DWM (aka Aero) since Vista.  But no Aero when you use RDP.  So you have to wait again.

Comment: Are you telling the parent to `RedrawWindow()`?  Telling the hidden dialog to redraw itself won't help.

Comment: So once I move my dialog using the `MoveWindow()` method I need to invoke the parent to redraw itself to cover up those pixels?

Comment: @HansPassant: Is that true for Windows 10 (or 8) too?

Comment: @LucasN: the parent window, the desktop window, other app windows, whatever is behind your window before you move/hide it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I've tried using `::RedrawWindow(hParent,parentRect,NULL,RDW_INVALIDATE)` but I am not see the window disappear. The parent is the only window that is behind it.

Comment: Update: I am trying the `ShowWindow()` method again and I am achieve results that are almost what I want. This is what I have `ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);` then `::RedrawWindow(GetParent(),NULL,NULL,RDW_INVALIDATE | RDW_UPDATENOW);`  then `::RedrawWindow(GetDesktopWindow(),NULL,NULL, RDW_INVALIDATE | RDW_UPDATENOW);`. but if I move my window by dragging it, the window won't hide.